# Implement user presence using Firestore db with Firebase Realtime db in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to set user presence in my React app using Firebase.
Everytime a user logs in the app I save it the a `users` collection and I display it as a list in my app.

I need to show the online status for each user, so I'm using Firebase Realtime db to update Firestore db, this is the whole AuthContext.js file :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from "react";
import { db, rtdb } from "../firebase/firebase-config";
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithPopup,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  serverTimestamp,
  getDocs,
  query,
  where,
  limit,
  updateDoc,
  doc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { ref as rtdbRef, set, onValue } from "firebase/database";

const authContext = createContext();

export function ProvideAuth({ children }) {
  const auth = useProvideAuth();
  return <authContext.Provider value={auth}>{children}</authContext.Provider>;
}

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(authContext);
};

function useProvideAuth() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const auth = getAuth();
  const [userLoading, setUserLoading] = useState(true);

  const getUserByUid = async (uid) => {
    let exists = false;
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
      query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", uid), limit(1))
    );
    querySnapshot.forEach(() => (exists = true));
    return exists;
  };

  const persistUser = async (user) => {
    const exists = await getUserByUid(user.uid);
    if (!exists) {
      await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        uid: user.uid,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        photoURL: user.photoURL,
        createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
        updatedAt: null,
      });
    }
  };

  const logIn = () =>
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        setUser(result.user);
        persistUser(result.user);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  const updateFirestoreUser = (user, status) => {
    if (user) {
      getDocs(
        query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid), limit(1))
      ).then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((u) => {
          updateDoc(doc(db, "users", u.id), {
            online: status,
            updatedAt: serverTimestamp(),
          });
        });
      });
    }
  };

  const logOut = () =>
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("SIGNOUT", user);
        updateFirestoreUser(user, false);
        setUser(false);
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  function checkAuthStatus() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
          resolve(user);
          setUser(user);

          const connectedRef = rtdbRef(rtdb, ".info/connected");
          const myConnectionsRef = rtdbRef(rtdb, `status`);
          onValue(connectedRef, (snap) => {
            if (snap.val() === true) {
              console.log("TRUE");
              if (user) {
                set(myConnectionsRef, "connected");
                updateFirestoreUser(user, true);
              }
            } else {
              console.log("FALSE");
              updateFirestoreUser(user, false);
            }
            //onDisconnect(myConnectionsRef)
              //.set("disconnected")
              //.then(() => {
              //   updateFirestoreUser(user, false);
              //});
          });
        });
      } catch {
        reject("api failed");
        setUser(false);
      }
    });
  }

  const getUser = async () => {
    setUserLoading(true);
    await checkAuthStatus();
    setUserLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

  return {
    user,
    logIn,
    logOut,
    userLoading,
  };
}
```

The `online` field in `users` collection gets updated when I login & logout, but not when I close the browser tab, it kinda works when I uncomment this part :

```
onDisconnect(myConnectionsRef)
 .set("disconnected")
 .then(() => {
    updateFirestoreUser(user, false);
});
```

But the changes reflect only in the Realtime db with no changes in Firestore db `users` collection, the string "disconnected" is added to the Realtime database but nothing changed in the user's entry I'm tying to update in the `then()` method.

Been stuck here for 2 days, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I just need the `online` field to be `true` when the app is opened and the user is logged in, and `false` when the user is signed out or the app is closed in the browser.

Comment: Did you implement Cloud Functions, as shown here? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence#updating_globally

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found no v9 documentation on that, so I couldn't do it as in the link your provided, instead I followed the docs here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample

Comment: That links shows how to get presence information into the Realtime Database. Without the Cloud Functions implementation I linked there is no way to get the presence information from RTDB into Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following the [presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample) in the documentation you linked, you will gets presence information in Realtime Database.

To get that information into Firestore, you'll need to implement a Cloud Function that triggers in the Realtime Database writes as shown in the section on [updating presence information in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence#updating_globally) in the documentation on [implementing presence on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence). That's the only way to get the presence information in Firestore, as that database doesn't have any `onDisconnect` like functionality that is required to build a presence system.

Comment: I understand, thanks a lot for the reply. Is there a v9 implementation for that? I'm using Firebase v9 in my project.

Comment: This code runs on Cloud Functions, where you'll be using the Admin SDK instead of the client-side JavaScript SDK. While there is a modular Admin SDK, I don't think that's been declared stable yet.

Comment: Ok I see, I appreciate the help!